# Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: Expected available quota

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-apps

I got an error when running my Google Sheets app script:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: Expected available quota.
```

This script go through a list of input in the first column and call an api to get values for each input.

Comment: Seems like a google internal error. Report it on their issues page. Also show full code here.

Comment: If you're making too many asynchronous calls you'll get that, in my testings, the script still runs as expected, the call is not lost. A snippet would be very helpful in this case.